# Autogenerated code in amazon swf flow framework throws syntax error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, amazon-swf

I am trying our amazon's SWF flow framework, but I am getting the below error and the project does not compile. I am using maven for my dependency management and I'm running my code from Intellij.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/meow/Arena/github/ProjectX/AWS/target/generated-sources/annotations/aws/swf/B_FlowFramework/B_WithAWSFlow/EditImageActivityClient.java:[24,18] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] /home/meow/Arena/github/ProjectX/AWS/target/generated-sources/annotations/aws/swf/B_FlowFramework/B_WithAWSFlow/EditImageActivityClient.java:[24,19] = expected
[ERROR] /home/meow/Arena/github/ProjectX/AWS/target/generated-sources/annotations/aws/swf/B_FlowFramework/B_WithAWSFlow/EditImageActivityClient.java:[24,25] illegal start of type
[ERROR] /home/meow/Arena/github/ProjectX/AWS/target/generated-sources/annotations/aws/swf/B_FlowFramework/B_WithAWSFlow/EditImageActivityClient.java:[29,18] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] /home/meow/Arena/github/ProjectX/AWS/target/generated-sources/annotations/aws/swf/B_FlowFramework/B_WithAWSFlow/EditImageActivityClient.java:[29,19] = expected
```

From Intellij, I've already confirmed if annotation processing is enabled from Settings -> Build, Execution,
    Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> **Enable
    Annotation Processing**

The codebase is on GitHub and its entry point is at https://github.com/vikkyhacks/ProjectX/blob/master/AWS/src/main/java/aws/swf/B_FlowFramework/B_WithAWSFlow/WorkflowStarter.java

Also adding pom.xml for easy reference,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>vikkyhacks.projectX.aws</groupId>
    <artifactId>AWS</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-swf-build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.635</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-iam</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.635</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.635</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: How exactly is this question related to AspectJ? Why the tag?

Comment: the swf flow framework uses it and some of its old versions require it to be added it to the pom.xml, anyway I'll remove it.

Comment: Consider using Cadence Workflow (https://cadenceworkflow.io/) which is an open source version of SWF which doesn't need code generation and AspectJ dependency.

Comment: @MaximFateev We are using this at work and I wanted to understand how amazon swf flow framework works, changing the framework is not an option for me.

Comment: Let me talk to your team and I can convince them to change it :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are using AWS SDK v1.11 and JDK 1.8. Did you try to upgrade AWS SDK to 2.0, or downgrade JDK to 1.6?

Check official documentation:

From **SDK 1.1**: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/README.md

> To run the SDK you will need Java 1.6+. For more information about the requirements and optimum settings for the SDK, please see the [Installing a Java Development Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/java-sdk/latest/developer-guide/setup-install.html#installing-a-java-development-environment) section of the developer guide.

From **SDK 2.0**: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/README.md

> To run the SDK you will need Java 1.8+. For more information about the requirements and optimum settings for the SDK, please see the [Installing a Java Development Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/setup-install.html##java-dg-java-env) section of the developer guide.

Also, AWS [recommends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html) the BOM method for specifying/including individual modules:

> **Specifying Individual SDK Modules (Recommended)**
>   To select individual SDK modules, use the AWS SDK for Java bill of materials (BOM) for Maven. This ensures that the modules you specify use the same version of the SDK, and that they're compatible with each other.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.X.X</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And an example for Kinesis and DynamoDB:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>kinesis</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note: for SWF, try artifactId as `swf`. Full list: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:software.amazon.awssdk

Comment: can you show some example of swf dependency instead of dynamodb ?

Comment: Try artifact id "swf"(https://search.maven.org/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/swf/2.8.0/jar) Complete list: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:software.amazon.awssdk

Comment: No luck with that link you gave, I am looking at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/aws-sdk-java/2.0.0-preview-1 but I don't see anything on SWF